# JPA save() involving @UniqueContraint fields

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, relational-database, unique-constraint

I'm using JPA with Hibernate implementation in a Spring project.
The entities are the following:

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"channel", "start", "end"})})
@Entity(name = "schedule")
public class Schedule {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "idSched", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idSched;

    @Column(name = "start", nullable = false)
    private Timestamp start;

    @Column(name = "end", nullable = false)
    private Timestamp end;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Channel.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="channel")
    private Channel channel;
}



@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"idChBusiness"})})
@Entity(name = "channel")
public class Channel {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idChPersistence;

    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name = "idChBusiness", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String idChBusiness;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Schedule.class, mappedBy="channel", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<Schedule> listSchedules;
}
```

Then I have a repository for each entity:

```
public interface ChannelRepository extends JpaRepository<Channel, Long>,
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<Channel>, ChannelRepositoryCustom {
...
}

public interface ScheduleRepository extends JpaRepository<Schedule, Long>,
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<Schedule> {
...         
}
```

I'm using JPA Repository's save() method to insert my entities. 
My main goal is to save a list of Schedule entities in a single save() query.

I assume the Schedules are unique in my input data. This is, there are no two Schedules with the same (channel, start, end) values, anyway, I'm preventing that with the @UniqueConstraint of Schedule entity.

However, in my input data there are different Schedule entities referring to Channels with the same idChBusiness. I do not want two Channel entities with the same idChBusiness in the table, and that's what I try to prevent with the @UniqueConstraint of Channel entity.

So, I can save a first Schedule with some channel attribute, and both entities are saved.

The problem is that when I try to save a second Schedule containing a channel attribute with the same idChBusiness as the first Schedule entity. Then idChBusiness @UniqueContraint is violated and the Channel entity is not saved, but neither is the parent Schedule entity.
Specifically, the Exception I'm getting is the following:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached
>   entity passed to persist: com.persistence.domain.Channel; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity
>   passed to persist: com.persistence.domain.Channel

But I think in this case the concept is more relevant than the specific error.

So, is there any JPA pattern to get this working and be able to save a list Schedule entities with a single save() query? Even if not, any other suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank you!

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried to solve it with @Jens Schauder approach. Here is the code:

```
public class DatabaseLoader() {

    ...

    public void doLoad(List<Schedule> lSched) {
        for (Schedule sched: lSched) {
            Channel ch = chServ.findByIdChBusiness(sched.getChannel().getIdChBusiness());
            if (ch != null) { // If a duplicate channel does exist -> Then remove it
                chServ.deleteChannel(ch);
            }
            schedServ.insertSchedule(sched);
        }
    }



@Service
@Transactional
public class ChannelService {

    ...

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void deleteChannel(Channel ch) {
        chRep.delete(ch);
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void insertChannel(Channel ch) {
        chRep.save(ch);
    }
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class ScheduleService {

    ...

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void insertSchedule(Schedule sched){
        schedRep.save(sched);
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

First schedule (with its channel) is sucessfully inserted. Next, I try to insert a second schedue whose channel attribute has the same idChBusiness as the channel attribute of the first schedule inserted.

Then the if-condition is satisfied so I should delete the channel in order to avoid a **@UniqueConstraint** violation over the Channel table. When I do it, that first schedule I just inserted gets deleted too, because of the **cascade=CascadeType.ALL** property.

Besides, while executing **schedServ.insertSchedule(sched)** sentence, I get the following PersistentObjectException:

> org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to
>   persist: com.persistence.domain.Channel

I tried it with **CascadeType.PERSIST** instead of **CascadeType.ALL** and the result is the same.

If I try to remove the CascadeType property, then Channel objects are never saved and I get the following exception:

> org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an
>   unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before
>   flushing: com.persistence.domain.Schedule.channel ->
>   com.persistence.domain.Channel

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you again!

Comment: This is getting rather convoluted and changing to a different question then how to handle unique constraints and their violation. I'd recommend creating a new question with a minimal but complete example, no "if I do this, that happens", but actual code.

Answer (score 2):

The unique constraint, as you have found yourself, keeps the transaction from completing successful. Therefore you should consider it only a safety net. It will prevent bad data in the database, but it doesn't help at all to resolve the problem.

The solution is to check first if duplicate exists, remove the duplicates and only then save your data.

Only in the (probably rare) condition that after you checked for duplicates and before actually storing the data a duplicate is introduced the UniqueConstraint will prevent the data entering the database. In most application this case is sufficiently handled by some generic "Oops, somehting went wrong. Please try again" exception handler.

Comment: Thank you Jens for your suggestion. I made an update. Take a look at it, please.